# Which NDB query function is more efficient to iterate through a big set of query results?

Tags: google-app-engine

I use NDB for my app and use iter() with limit and starting cursor to iterate through 20,000 query results in a task.  A lot of time I run into timeout error.

Timeout: The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.

The way I make the call is like this:

```
results = query.iter(limit=20000, start_cursor=cursor, produce_cursors=True)
for item in results:
  process(item)
save_cursor_for_next_time(results.cursor_after().urlsafe())
```

I can reduce the limit but I thought a task can run as long as 10 mins.  10 mins should be more than enough time to go through 20000 results.  In fact, on a good run, the task can complete in just about a minute.

If I switched to fetch() or fetch_page(), would they be more efficient and less likely to run into the timeout error?  I suspect there's a lot of overhead in iter() that causes the timeout error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch is not really any more efficient they all use the same mechanism, unless you know how many entities you want upfront - then fetch can be more efficient as you end up with just one round trip.

You can increase the batch size for iter, that can improve things. See  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#kwdargs_options

From the docs the default batch size is 20, which would mean for 20,000 entities a lot of batches.

Other things that can help.  Consider using map and or map_async on the processing, rather than explicitly calling process(entity)  Have a read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#map  also introducing async into your processing can mean improved concurrency.

Having said all of that you should profile so you can understand where the time is used.  For instance the delays could be in your `process` due to things you are doing there.

Answer (score 0):

There are other things to conside with ndb like context caching, you need to disable it. But I also used iter method for these. I also made an ndb version of the mapper api with the old db.

Here is my ndb mapper api that should solve timeout problems and ndb caching and easily create this kind of stuff:
http://blog.altlimit.com/2013/05/simple-mapper-class-for-ndb-on-app.html

with this mapper api you can create it like or you can just improve it too.

```
class NameYourJob(Mapper):

    def init(self):
        self.KIND = YourItemModel
        self.FILTERS = [YourItemModel.send_email == True]

    def map(self, item):
        # here is your process(item)
        # process here
        item.send_email = False
        self.update(item)

# Then run it like this
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
deferred.defer(NameYourJob().run, 50,  # <-- this is your batch 
    _target='backend_name_if_you_want', _name='a_name_to_avoid_dups')
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why the context caching needs to be disabled in the mapper?  What does that really help?

Comment: It's been a while but if I remember correctly I did it so it doesn't create a context cache when you update an entity which builds up and might create unnecessary overhead on the instance it's running on.

Answer (score 0):

For potentially long query iterations, we use a time check to ensure slow processing can be handled. Given the disparities in GAE infrastructure performance, you will likely never find an optimal processing number. The code excerpt below is from an on-line maintenance handler we use which generally runs within ten seconds. If not, we get a return code saying it needs to be run again thanks to our timer check. In your case, you would likely break the process after passing the cursor to your next queue task. Here is some sample code which is edited down to hopefully give you a good idea of our logic. One other note: you may choose to break this up into smaller bites and then fan out the smaller tasks by re-enqueueing the task until it completes. Doing 20k things at once seems very aggressive in GAE's highly variable environment. HTH -stevep

```
def over_dt_limit(start, milliseconds):
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() - start
    mt = float(dt.seconds * 1000) + (float(dt.microseconds)/float(1000))
    if mt > float(milliseconds):
        return True
    return False


    #set a start time
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    # handle a timeout issue inside your query iteration
    for item in query.iter():
        # do your loop logic
        if over_dt_limit(start, 9000):
            # your specific time-out logic here
            break
```